# How to properly use QWebSocket::sendBinaryMessage() method from a C++ client?

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, client-server, binary-data

There are C++ Qt client & server. Following code works fine and the connection happens between the client and the server:

```
QWebSocket webSocket;  // defined somewhere
...
QUrl url;
url.setScheme("ws");  // SSL encryption disabled
url.setHost(serverName);  // "127.0.0.1" (can be "www.abc.com" too)
url.setPort(portNumber);  // 2000
webSocket.open(url);  // connects with the server properly
PRINT(url.toString());  // output: "ws://127.0.0.1:2000"
```

While sending the binary data, the function returns 0 instead of the number of bytes:

```
// though the message.size() is 80 bytes; the method returns 0
webSocket.sendBinaryMessage(QByteArray(message.data(), message.size()));
```

Note that, the `QWebSocketServer` works as expected.
We also have a Javascript client. That connects & sends the binary message properly. The only addition in that client is below:

```
webSocketJS.binaryType = "arraybuffer";  // <--- Javascript code
```

But such provision is not found in `QWebSocket` or I may have missed it.

**Question**: How to correctly send the binary data over the web connection?

---

For those interested, the server [pseudo] code is like below:

```
auto pWebSocket = WebServer.nextPendingConnection();
QObject::connect(pWebSocket, &QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived,
                 [&] (const QByteArray& message) { DataRead(message, rManager); });  // This slot is not called as of now
```

Comment: I assume you've checked the values returned by [`QWebSocket::error`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#error), [`QWebSocket::errorString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#errorString) etc.?

Comment: Also check `QWebSocket::closeReason()`, could be that the socket is closed, because if sendBinaryMessage returns 0, it means that no data was sent.

Comment: @G.M., Yes I have checked those and they seems not problem makers. To ManuelH, yes that's an important thing. I have to get it checked. -- In general, it seems that I have got the root cause. I am not checking for the `connected()` signal. The code is running too fast, to be able to wait for this signal to be shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no mention of how the `QWebSocket::connected()` signal is treated.
Due to internet delay and initial handshakes, the `WebSocketServer` may take some time to establish a connection. Ideally the binary/text message should be sent only after the `connected()` is received.

Before making a connection using `webSocket.open(url)`, you should be handling this signal:

```
... // same code
   QObject::connect(&webSocket, &QWebSocket::connected,
                    [&] () 
                    {
                      webSocket.sendBinaryMessage(QByteArray(message.data(), message.size()));
                      // ... set some internal state suggesting the established connection
                    }
   webSocket.open(url);
```

Above is just a pseudo code to show that the first `sendBinaryMessage()` should be sent after the `connect()` signal. Ideally in real world code, you may want to set some state, which informs the client that the connection is established.

Similarly as mentioned in the comments, we should be checking for errors and disconnections as well.